# Opencart site move to Godaddy; Error: Could not make a database link

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I just moved site to godaddy one hosting account to other. I have connected database correctly. Have change paths / database info in config.php and admin/config.php , but i am still getting this issue and not able to solve it. I have followed all tutorials online but nothing helps.

Error I am getting:

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'asnso'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/host/public_html/domain/system/library/db/mysql.php on line 7

Notice: Error: Could not make a database link using asnso@localhost in /home/host/public_html/domain/system/library/db/mysql.php on line 8
```

SO, can anyone please help me. I will really appreciate your help.
Thanks

Comment: just to make sure: you created the same user 'asnso' with the correct password and granted access with the correct permissions to that database? and the user is 'asnso' with no prefix?

Comment: Do you this, it could be some issue on hosting - server side?

Comment: This is the server problem. Please talk to server administrator.

Comment: sure. I will. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check your password or try resetting the password. Also check host name might not be localhost. to check this go to phpMyAdmin and see in the right panel. Refer below image..

[image: phpMyadmin]

Comment: thanks, i reset password to numbers and digits simply and it starts working. 

Looks like Password Decode Failure. But my databse connection is working correctly now.
https://github.com/opencart/opencart/issues/3185